# Upper bound a binomial-like summation

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I am attempting to prove a non-trivial upper bound on the following expression.

Let $0 < r \leq 1$, and let $p$ be a positive integer.

My summation is the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\left\lfloor \frac{p}{2} \right\rfloor {p \choose 2k}r^{2k} = 1 + {p \choose 2}r^2 + {p \choose 4}r^4 + \ldots$$

Note that when $r = 1$, I think that it is easy to see that this summation is $2^{p-1}$, as we are essentially counting the number of even subsets of a set of size $p$ (right?).

I'm not sure how to bound it as a function of $r$ and $p$, however.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need an upper bound when the sum is given by $\frac{(1+r)^p + (1-r)^p}{2}$?

Comment: @user6312: No problem. Let your answer stay on so that this questions gets an answer

Comment: @user6312: No problem. It doesn't really matter as long as both our answers are the same.

Comment: Thank you for this quick reply.  If it's not too much to ask, can you tell why this is true?  (I suppose I could probably convince myself by induction?)

Comment: You don't even need induction, just the binomial formula.  $(1+r)^n=\sum \binom{n}{k}r^k$ and $(1-r)^n=\sum \binom{n}{k}(-r)^k$.  If you add them, all the terms where $k$ is even are the same in both sums, and all the terms where $k$ is odd cancel each other out.

Answer (score 2):

I'll flesh out the details from the comments:

Recall from the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) that $(1+x)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n \choose k}x^k$. Similarly, $(1-x)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n \choose k}(-x)^k$. If we add these two together, we get:

$$\begin{align} 
(1+x)^n + (1-x)^n &= [1 + x {n \choose 1}  + x^2  {n \choose 2}  + x^3  {n \choose 3}  + x^4  {n \choose 4}  + ...] + \\
&\; + \, [1 - x  {n \choose 1}  + x^2  {n \choose 2}  - x^3  { n \choose 3 }  + x^4  { n \choose 4}  + ...]
\end{align}$$

So we see that all the odd-powered terms cancel, while the even-powered terms reinforce. So the exact sum is $\dfrac{(1+x)^n + (1-x)^n}{2}$.

But there is one distinction between this solution and the problem you asked: since your question only goes up to $\lfloor \frac{p}{2} \rfloor$, if $p$ is odd then we see that the last term of the expansion is left out. But this is minor - and is easily remedied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation!  I guess it is quite simple, now that I see the answer.

Comment: @Tom: no problem! I didn't really do any of the work, it all came from the comments.